# Tab Index in controls of a GroupBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a groupBox that I have put three RadioButtons and one TextBox in it. Their tab index is like 5,6,7,8 beginning form radio buttons and ending in the text box but in my form when I tab , it goes to the radio button that its radio button is selected and with next tab it doesn't go to the next radio button but it goes to that text box.
So I was wondering if this is the normal behavior of how it should work or it is something that I have done wrong?

Comment: Have you got any sample code?

Comment: There is no code! I am setting them in Properties windows of the controls in the VS designer IDE.

Comment: In that case, it just sounds like an issue with your tabbing index(check the number for the text box). Other than that I can't help you as I've never used the designer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's standard behavior with the radio buttons that are grouped together in some panel.  You tab to one of them and then arrow to go to the other ones.  Makes sense to me - probably wouldn't want to have a tab change the value of a radio button group, right?  Otherwise keyboard navigation would be problematic.  When you tab into a radio button group, it tabs to the selected one.